# Visual Studio extension development, callback for detecting file deletion from solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I'm making a Visual studio extension, where something happens when a file is saved and when it is deleted. I can detect when the current file is about to be saved using IVsRunningDocTableEvents3

I was trying to find a callback for when a file is deleted from the solution explorer window. I've tried searching for it in the VS sdk 2017 but its really tough to search.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IVsTrackProjectDocuments2.AdviseTrackProjectDocumentsEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstrackprojectdocuments2.advisetrackprojectdocumentsevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to listen when a file is deleted.