# vsct listen for ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded not catching anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsct

VS2019 16.5.0 preview 1

I'm trying to catch events when a project has an item added, deleted, or renamed.

I am catching when the solution is opened and closed, or when a project is added or removed, but I am just not catching  when a single file is added to a project.

```
public DTE2 _dte2;
private Events2 _events2;
private SolutionEvents _SolutionEvents;
private ProjectItemsEvents _ProjectItemsEvents;

public MyProject()
{
    _dte2 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2;

    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.AfterClosing += SolutionEvents_AfterClosing;
    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened += SolutionEvents_Opened;
    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded += SolutionEvents_ProjectAdded;
    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectRemoved += SolutionEvents_ProjectRemoved;
    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.BeforeClosing += SolutionEvents_SolutionBeforeClosing;
    _dte2.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectRenamed += SolutionEvents_ProjectRenamed;

    _events2 = (Events2)_dte.Events;
    _ProjectItemsEvents = _events2.ProjectItemsEvents;

    _events2.ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded += ItemAddedHandler;
    _events2.ProjectItemsEvents.ItemRemoved += ItemRemovedHandler;
    _events2.ProjectItemsEvents.ItemRenamed += ItemRenamedHandler;
}

private void ItemAddedHandler(ProjectItem projectItem) 
{
} <- breakpoint here

private void ItemRemovedHandler(ProjectItem projectItem)
{
} <- breakpoint here

private void ItemRenamedHandler(ProjectItem projectItem, string oldName)
{
} <- breakpoint here
```

Putting breakpoints on the ItemAddedHandler, ItemRemovedHandler, or ItemRenamedHandler has no effect at all.  These methods never get called when I add, rename, or delete a file from a project when the extension is running in the experimental instance.

I found references to other people having similar problems but these were all related to garbage collection, and I don't believe this is my problem as I have a reference to the events2 and projectItemsEvents.

Comment: Try to change _events2.ProjectItemsEvents. to _ProjectItemsEvents.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257869/visual-studio-extension-development-callback-for-detecting-file-deletion-from-s

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thanks sergey.  Can you clarify what you mean by "Try to change _events2.ProjectItemsEvents. to _ProjectItemsEvents"?  Do you mean change the lines such as "_events2.ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded += ItemAddedHandler;" to "_ProjectItemsEvents.ItemAdded += ItemAddedHandler;"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Figured out why it's not working for me.  The ProjectItemsAdded or deleted events don't work for .NET core projects.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/241589/projectitemsevents-dont-trigger-into-vsix-package.html